# Mongodb update limited number of documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with 100 million documents. I want to safely update a number of the documents (by safely I mean update a document only if it hasn't already been updated). Is there an efficient way to do it in Mongo?

I was planning to use the $isolated operator with a limit clause but it appears mongo doesn't support limiting on updates.

This seems simple but I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot consul you anymore than giving you a JIRA link I am afraid: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1599

Comment: Thanks. I signed up just to vote for this issue :-) Now to find some convoluted workaround until the feature is implemented ...

Comment: "safely" - I'm not clear why limit is related to this - if you plan on updating all the documents and you use "{multi:true}" then each document will be updated only once.  Could you explain your exact use case?  I suspect there may be a work-around.

Comment: I'm not updating all documents -- it will be un unknown number of documents (e.g. maybe the first 100 documents or maybe the first 1000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Sammaye, it doesn't look like there is a "proper" way to do this.
My workaround was to create a [sequence as outlined on the mongo site](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) and simply add a 'seq' field to every record in my collection. Now I have a unique field which is reliably sortable to update on.

Reliably sortable is important here. I was going to just sort on the auto-generated _id but I quickly realized that natural order is NOT the same as ascending order for ObjectId's (from [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) it looks like the string value takes precedence over the object value which matches the behavior I observed in testing). Also, it is entirely possible for a record to be relocated on disk which makes the natural order unreliable for sorting.

So now I can query for the record with the smallest 'seq' which has NOT already been updated to get an inclusive starting point. Next I query for records with 'seq' greater than my starting point and skip (it is important to skip since the 'seq' may be sparse if you remove documents, etc...) the number of records I want to update. Put a limit of 1 on that query and you've got a non-inclusive endpoint. Now I can issue an update with a query of 'updated' = 0, 'seq' >= my starting point and < my endpoint. Assuming no other thread has beat me to the punch the update should give me what I want.

Here are the steps again:

1. create an auto-increment sequence using findAndModify
2. add a field to your collection which uses the auto-increment sequence
3. query to find a suitable starting point: db.xx.find({ updated: 0 }).sort({ seq: 1 }).limit(1)
4. query to find a suitable endpoint: db.xx.find({ seq: { $gt: startSeq }}).sort({ seq: 1 }).skip(updateCount).limit(1)
5. update the collection using the starting and ending points: db.xx.update({ updated: 0, seq: { $gte: startSeq }, seq: { $lt: endSeq }, $isolated: 1}, { updated: 1 },{ multi: true })

Pretty painful but it gets the job done.