# How to update limited records in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, limit

Well, In mysql,i can use follow sql:

> update something set a=1 where b=2 limit 10;

But in MongoDB,i can just do it like this:

> db.something.update({b:2},{$set:{a:1}},{multi:true})

if the 'multi' option is not setted to be True,it justs update 1 record,but i 
wont to update limited records, how to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590890/how-to-limit-number-of-updating-documents-in-mongodb

Comment: indeed it is a dupe - for reference the relevant feature request is https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1599

Comment: I found a even more earlier topic:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237050/mongodb-update-limited-number-of-documents。